# combining left and right functions with different lengths

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know how to use left and right functions separately. I have various length cells and I would like to get the mid range

```
:ns:Ustrd:SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT ACCORDING :/ns:Ustrd:
:ns:Ustrd:SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT:/ns:Ustrd:
:ns:Ustrd:SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT ACCORDING to invoice 1234 :/ns:Ustrd:
```

I need a formula that would take everything from the left - 10 and from right -11
to read as following

```
SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT ACCORDING
SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT
SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT ACCORDING to invoice 1234
```

Answer (score 1):

Use MID:

```
=MID(A1,11,LEN(A1) - 22)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way: with your string in A1

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,":/ns:Ustrd:",""),":ns:Ustrd:","")
```